# How do you differentiate a subject complement from the object of a verb?

Tags: noun-phrases

In these two sentences there's a noun phrase being used with different intents in each one, but how do you tell when it is a subject complement and when it is the object of the verb? Because to me it seems like in both cases it could be answering the question "what?" to the verb (?

> "It was **a rich hot smell which seemed like an emanation from his early childhood**" (subject complement)

> "His nostrils detected **a rich hot smell which seemed like an emanation from his early childhood**" (object of the verb "detected")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the same if you simplify it:

It *was* a smell...   *was* is a copulative (linking) verb, so *smell* is a complement.

He *detected* a smell... *detected* is a transitive verb, so *smell* is its object.

Comment: Okay, that's quite helpful, thanks :)

Comment: Precisely. All the extra words apart from ***smell*** are a syntactically irrelevant distraction in the context of this specific question. And  ***that*** shoud be the main takeaway from this answer: When trying to understand syntactic relationships, *remove all syntactically irrelevant text from the utterance under consideration*.